# Do dataframe has to be the last command in pandas to show output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

As I have to show dataframe for the output and do file handling and error logging.
So I created the .ipynb file in pycharm and did all mentioned above? But I am able to see dataframe in my out window as I have mentioned dataframe in my one of the methods(not the last one).

**Earlier it was showing me dataframe when my program was simple and dataframe was last command.**

Can anyone tell me what will be best way to deal with these type of situations.
I tried running in Jupyter Notebook also that whole program but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

A notebook can have many cells. The value of the last expression in each cell is displayed.

[image]
([image source](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-5-0-909c6c172d78))

So if you wish to display the value of the dataframe,
let it be the last expression in a cell, and then put the file handling / logging in a subsequent cell.

Answer (score 1):

By default the interactivity is set to only print out last expression. You can change it by changing this setting -

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity

You can do it like this

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```